# Return Value from VBA Call Shell(whatever_cmd)

Tags: linux, vba, perl, shell, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to execute a plink command to invoke perl script on a Linux platform which returning a value or a response in string.

I tried:

```
retval = Shell("plink perl test.pl")
```

where test.pl return value with either OK or NOT OK

But I couldn't capture those string in the retval variable.
When I track the retval, it appear to be random integer.

Is there a way to capture the right return value or string?

Comment: Is the random integer between 0 and 255? Are you sure your `Shell` command returns the _output_ and not the exit code of the program?

Comment: At first I thought this was a Linux, but it's really a Windows VBA question, right?  Seems like only the target computer is Linux, but that's really irrelevant to how to make the Shell call from VBA.  Besides the issue of how to capture the output (not the PID or response value) from your shell call, I don't think you're using `plink` correctly.  Maybe you dropped it, but I think you need to specify `user@host` and probably a password too.

Comment: Oops...
I used the dos putty command as:

Perl_Cmd = "perl " & "/usr/script/a.pl"
Shell_Cmd = "plink root@" & "123.123.123.123" & " -pw root " & Perl_Cmd

RetVal = Shell(Shell_Cmd)


The return value can be more than 255...or rather 4 to 5 digits number.

However, when I execute the a.pl in the linux base, the return would be OK or NOT OK.
I know that the a.pl (perl script) is working fine but not he returning value to the VBA.

Answer (score 0):

[Shell's return value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe736fyk(v=vs.90).aspx) is the program's process ID. To get the actual output of the program (as you would see from a prompt), [create a wscript object](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156605.aspx) and call the `.exec` method. Try something like this:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set objExecObject = objShell.Exec("plink perl test.pl")

Do While objExecObject.Status = WshRunning
    DoEvents
    'Could add a counter here to exit if it takes too long
Loop

 objExecObject.StdOut.ReadAll
```