# How to return data from a Shell command in VB6 to a variable

Tags: vb6

I am trying to get the version number from an .exe using a Shell command in one of my VB6 projects.

the code goes like this:

> ```
> BoVersion = Shell("wmic datafile where name='& boPath & ' get version")
>
>     BoVersionArr() = Split(BoVersion, ".")
>     
>         boVerYear = CStr(BoVersionArr(0))
>         boVerMonth = CStr(BoVersionArr(1))
>         boVerDay = CStr(BoVersionArr(2))
>         boVerMin = CStr(BoVersionArr(3))
> ```

when I run the command from CMD I get

[image]

but in the VB6 project, I try to assign this into a variable and I get the following,
[image]

Does anyone know if I can convert this into a string or how to approach this? I am trying to split this and convert it into a date format which I have working.

Comment: I used to do this by redirecting  the output from the shell command to a text file using "> filename", checking if the file exists in vb, then reading the value from the text file.

Comment: Here's a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784367/capture-output-value-from-a-shell-command-in-vba/32600510) to get you started. Or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37841250/return-value-from-vba-call-shellwhatever-cmd).

Comment: If you just want a file's version number simply use the `GetFileVersion()` method available [via FSO](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-can-i-determine-the-version-number-of-a-file/).  If not WMI is COM based, you can call it directly.

Comment: Here's what VB6's help states about `Shell()`: "Runs an executable program and returns a Variant (Double) representing **the program's task ID** if successful, otherwise it returns zero." _(Emphasize mine)_, i.e. `Shell()` doesn't return what you hope it returns (the actual program's output).